# how to add a vertical scroll bar within a table (razor view)

Tags: html, jquery-ui, scrollbar

I am struggling to to add a a vertical scroll bar in my view(razor/html).
i would like to place it within my data which wraps my data. I have made attempt but wasn't successful.

In needs of some help if possible.

```
<table id = "MenuItem"  class="promo full-width alternate-rows" style="text-align: center; ">  <!-- Cedric Kehi DEMO CHANGE -->



            <tr>
                <th>Product Code
                </th>

                <th>Description <!-- JACK EDIT -->
                </th>
                <th>Product Size
                </th>
                <th>Product Material
                </th>
                <th>Excluded?
                </th>
                <th>Order
                </th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>


        <tbody id ="scroll" style="overflow : scroll">


        @foreach (var item in Model.IndexList.OrderBy(x => x.ShuffleFunction))
        {




            <tr id ="trendingDisplay" data-model="model-1">



                    <td class="center-text">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductCode)
                    </td>
                   @* <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductTemplate.Description)
                    </td>*@
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Size.SizeTitle)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Material.MaterialName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.GreyOut)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShuffleFunction)
                    </td>
                    <td class="center-text nowrap">
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Edit", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Edit", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text edit" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Details", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Details", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text details" })
                        @Html.ActionLink(" ", "Delete", new { id = item.ProductID }, new { title = "Delete", @class = "anchor-icon-no-text delete" })

  <input class ="greyout" type="checkbox"  name="grey" id="trending" />


                </td>

            </tr>



        }


            </tbody>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap your table element in a container and give it a fixed height and set the overflow property.

```
<div style="height:600px;overflow-y:scroll">
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: seems to work but its horizontal, i would like to be vertical which will allow me to scroll up and down